# need to captialise characters of a string in visual studio text editor

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Is there a way I can automatically change a string to the upper version.

For example:

```
select * from table
```

would be:

```
SELECT * FROM table
```

After selecting both select and table and applying such a function. Typically I create the sql in a web editor, then copy paste it into my code, but have to format it a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use general settings : Control Shift U ? It's under Edit | Advanced

Comment: @jonynz: If this answered your question, can you click the tick associated with this? This will mark this as the accepted answer :)

Comment: was trying to, but it said i have to wait 37 seconds :( will do shortly

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to into the "[SQL Refactor](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Refactor/index.htm)" product offered by Red-Gate. The product will automatically layout and format your SQL queries.

Comment: won't help as I'm using postgresql through phppgadmin, thanks for the comment regardless